# Numerical Derivative

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods

I have a set of data that is generated from an equation that has an exponentially decaying source term. I use a five point central difference formula to estimate the first derivative at each point. Unfortunately there appears to be numerical problems (perhaps oscillations). I should also note that the data change slowly where these numerical problems seem to occur.

I am confident I have applied the algorithm correctly because another set of data turns out smooth. Can anyone provide insight into what might cause this?

Comment: I think you are having [loss of significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) situation. Not much you can do.

Answer (score 1):

As Somos says, taking numerical derivatives is dangerous from a loss of significance point of view.  If $h$ is small, $f(x+h)$ can be very close to $f(x)$ and when you subtract them you lose many significant figures.  As $h$ gets small the problem gets worse.  As $f'(x)$ gets close to $0$ the problem gets worse.

If your curves are smooth, the first derivative may not be changing rapidly and taking $h$ larger may solve your problem.  Using fewer points may also help.  It will be less accurate in the sense that neglected terms are larger, but it can be more accurate in the sense that the loss of significance is less.  You need to balance these.

If you have a(n approximate) functional form you can fit the form and take the derivative analytically.  The parameters of the form may be slowly varying

Comment: Thanks for the insight. That seems to make some sense. Say for example that I use central differences with just two points, how would I go about deriving the proper coefficients, or would they not change from 1 and then I would just divide by 4 instead of 2? Any further insight you could provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For a first derivative you can use just two points as the definition says.  $\frac {df(x)}{dx} \approx \frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$.  If the derivative is not huge, the difference in the numerator must be small, so losing precision unless you can remove a factor of $h$ analytically.  The problem is even worse if you need second derivatives.